# A File Server and Sockets

Tags: sockets, networking

I am working on a file server program ( written in C) that delivers the content of several files to clients. Both the file server and the client machines run Linux. I would like to reduce the time for the transfer of the files between the servers and the clients.

I am currently using sockets to transfer the files, with one socket per client. If I were to use two sockets per client, would the time for the file transfer go down? Note, the hardware is such that there is just one physical path to the machine.

Thanks Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what is your bottleneck. In general, no, two or more sockets wouldn't speed up the transfer, as if everything is implemented correctly your bottleneck is the network itself. The first thing that comes to mind is the size of your socket send/receive buffers, as often the system defaults are quite small numbers (e.g. 8KB). Try to increase send buffer on server and receive buffer on client.

If you use TCP it's already well tuned for such use case. Still there're some known issues with it, e.g. using fat channels over long distance. Providing more info about your environment/implementation can help to get better answers.